# JDBC PostgreSQL CopyManager.copyIn Returns Zero

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have the following code which always yields zero in the return value `nRows`.

```
CopyManager cm = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) connection);
long nRows = cm.copyIn
(
    "COPY myschema.mytable FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv)"
    , new StringReader(strRowData)
);
```

We verified that the data is in fact in the database, we just can't get the return value to work for logging purposes despite [what the documentation says](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyIn.html#endCopy--).  Anybody has an idea?

EDIT: The fact that our `myschema.mytable` is actually referencing its sub tables, which are named in the form of `myschema.mytable_[yyyymmdd]`, may contribute to the issue.

EDIT2: I tried tweaking the database table so that it no longer references to any sub table, then the readings worked flawlessly.  However, when I changed the table back to the way it was, the readings failed again.  So apparently this is something to do at a lower level, either JDBC or even SQL.  For the time being, I'll try to make a workaround to completely evade the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Long affectedRows = 0L;
CopyManager cm = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) connection);
CopyIn ci = cm.copyIn("COPY myschema.mytable FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv)");
ci.writeToCopy(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
affectedRows = ci.endCopy();
```

Comment: Despite the fact that CopyManager.copyIn()` is using `CopyIn.writeToCopy()` internally, I gave it a try.  But it doesn't work.

Comment: i am using exact same and its returns affected rows. can you write 2-3 lines from your csv file. and create table and insert script hier. [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

COPY myschema.mytable FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '''' HEADER CSV

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/